# Domain, DTO and MVVM models (WPF) - where to put INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to create WPF app with MVVM pattern as a layer of my solution.
Solution have: Domain, DAL (returns Domain objects), DTO, BLL (returns DTO objects).

The problem is that to implement MVVM pattern it seems to me that i have to duplicate my Domain models in WPF project so I can implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface on them? Then I also have to map these models to DTO so i could use BLL services?

Comment: What is your actual problem though? You're explaining what you want to do but I don't see a problem

Comment: @chinloyal I just have a bad feeling about this, but seems like i need to suppress it cause it's fine to do it this way :D thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inotifypropertychanged needs to be implemented on anything you bind AND you want to notify when a property changes.
You don't always need that notification.
For example.
You're editing a record, you make changes.
Maybe that's all you're doing with that data and the only bound field is that one you just typed into.
Which means you could, potentially, just bind a dto property with a plain get and set.
Although - this should be presented from a viewmodel which implements inpc because there's a very subtle memory leak waiting to catch you out otherwise.

Back to our imaginary app though.
Why might we not want to bind straight to an entity framework or dto object?

How about when you try and save thosee changes.  Validation fails. 
But you changed that object - those new values are naughty values.
The user is "forced" to fix them or you somehow back out your changes.
How do you back em out?
Are you editing some dto?
Because your user just broke that data.
If you have some collection of data cached somewhere, are you changing one of those directly?

Obviously, you could go re-read that data out the database again.
There again if you don't let them edit that dto then you don't need to do that.

I would usually copy data from a dto into a viewmodel and work in that.
I use a reflection based property copying routine that identified common properties between two types.
I validate that viewmodel as each property transfers to the vm and all of the object on commmit.
It's values are copied into a dto and sent back to the repository or UoW update method.

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels are designed to work with Views, so they don't always map 1-1 with domain objects.

- Sometimes a view needs to display data from multiple domain objects.
- Sometimes a view only needs some of the data from a domain object.
- Sometimes a view needs data that's only relevant to the view (selected item for example).

So, the question of how to populate data into the ViewModel can be complex. Most of the time I just skip the DTO and have the ViewModel get the data itself. Or if that's not possible have the DAL try to populate the ViewModel as if it was the DTO. It really depends on how the rest of the apps infrastructure works. In general I try to have as little number of layers as possible. Ideally I have my ViewModel getting the data it needs as directly as possible.